# DateTime(get_field('event_date'))

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying out DateTime function to be able to convert date from actual format to just month as stated below;

i am getting error when trying to parse datetime as below;

CODE

```
$eventDate = new DateTime(get_field('event_date'));

echo $eventDate->format('M')
```

ERROR

> "fatal error: uncaught exception:
>
> datetime::+construct(: failed to parse time string (29/06/2017) at
>   position
>
> 0(02): unexpected character in /home/xxxxx/front-page.php line 33"

If i replace the **get_field** with **the_field** it return date format 29/06/2017

Comment: What do you get with `get_field('event_date')` only?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$event_date = get_field('event_date');
$event_date = date(‘Y-m-d’, strtotime($event_date));

$eventDate = new DateTime($event_date);

echo $eventDate->format('M')
```

Answer (score 1):

From the ACF Information on using date fields... [ACF Date Output](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/date-output/) and here [ACF Date Picker](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/)

Advanced Custom Fields stores the date in 'Ymd'

> Return Format The date format that is returned when loading the value.
>   Please note that the value is always saved as Ymd (YYYYMMDD) in the
>   database

.

```
<?php 

/*
*  Create PHP DateTime object from Date Piker Value
*  this example expects the value to be saved in the format: yymmdd (JS) = Ymd (PHP)
*/

$format_in = 'Ymd'; // the format your value is saved in (set in the field options)
$format_out = 'M'; // the format you want to end up with

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format_in, get_field('date_picker'));

echo $date->format( $format_out );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your contributions.

Eventually, the Advance custom field plugin that i am using is set to a different date format while i need to return date in 'Ymd'. So, all i need to do is to adjust the date format in the custom field.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugefy.jpg)